# Exclude WCS/WebSphere Commerce 8 categories that are not relevant to current catalog and categories in keyword search?

Tags: solr, websphere, commerce, wcs

We have bunch of item(s) in more than 1 customer catalog under customer specific categories. For example when we search for 'candy' we see items that have given text and also items that are in a category with word 'candy' in category name(s). The items are valid for the catalog but not relevant for current keyword search. I tried commenting OOB WCS/ WebSphere Commerce 8 category search profile but that didn't exclude category search from the results. How do we tell SOLR/WCS Search to limit the search to current catalog categories only, to exclude text search in other catalog categories as well?
Would it be possible to filter query(fq) expression without including or excluding full list of categories in the catalog?